How can I map only SharePoint groups with Modern Audience targeting for Event web part or Site level?
For SharePoint communication site I want to target audience for different countries. So simply I want to map audience targeting with SharePoint groups only. In list setting I have changed to SharePoint group and it is working in list if we got to list and we add or edit any event from that list.
But when I'm trying to add any event from the Event web part and I'm trying to target it all the M365 groups are displaying up. I want only SharePoint groups to be displayed.
How can I map only SharePoint groups with Modern Audience targeting for Event web part or Site level? Only SP groups should be visible for Audience targeting.

Microsoft only supports using Azure Active Directory groups (including security groups, Microsoft 365 groups, and AAD dynamic groups) for audience targeting in modern experience (for web parts, site navigation links, etc.).
Currently, SharePoint groups are not supported for audience targeting in the "Events" web part. So, you will not be able to use those for audience targeting on the modern web parts in SharePoint.

Microsoft documentations:

Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site
Use the SharePoint Events web part
Target navigation, news, files, links, and web parts to specific audiences

